# Can a view have a drawer?

Tags: cocoa, drawer

In Cocoa, a drawer can be attached to a window using the `setParentWindow:` method. Is it possible to attach a drawer to a view in some way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. It wouldn't make sense to put a drawer on a view. For example how do you put a drawer on a button?

It seems Apple are using drawers less in each release of OS X. They seem to be being replaced with HUD style inspectors and 'inline' drawers. For example, Preview in 10.4 had a drawer, but in 10.5 this was replaced with a list that appeared inside the main window.

Answer (score 1):

Matt Gemmell's attached window might serve your purposes or inspire a solution of your own: http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/03/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass